# Do an ZendX autocomplete in a layout

Tags: zend-framework, layout, autocomplete

I would like to use ZendX_Jquery autocomplete ***in a partial***, **which is in my layout**.
How can I do that :
My layout :

```
<div class="prefix_11 grid_5" id="header_search_engine">
    <?php  echo $this->partial("/common/_search_engine.phtml");  ?>
</div>
```

An action :

```
public function autocompleteAction($search='') {
   $this->view->autocompleteElement = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_AutoComplete('ac');
   $this->view->autocompleteElement->setJQueryParam('source', '/searchengine/getsearch');
   $this->view->autocompleteElement->setJQueryParam('minLength',
   $this->configApplication->autocomplete->max_cars);
}
```

How can I use it in the partial, in the layout ?

How can i send the **autocompleteElement** in the partial view ?,

Thanks to help.

Fabrice

Answer (score 2):

@fabrice

I had the same problem using autocomplete with my layout and I have solved it with the following:

- Use placeholder for my searchBox
- Create a Zend_Controller_Plugin that extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
- in predispatch execute method renderUiWidgetElement of autocomplete element.
- set the placeholder with the form

Example:

```
class myLibrary_Controller_Plugin_SearchBox extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->searchBox();
    }

    public function searchBox()
    {
        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
        $viewRenderer->initView();
        $view = $viewRenderer->view;

        $searchForm = new Application_Form_JQueryForm();
        $searchForm->acProduct->renderUiWidgetElement();
        $view->placeholder('searchBox')->set($searchForm);
    }
}
```

The key is to launch method `renderUiWidgetElement();`. Without it, the layout will not add the neccesary javascript to the autocomplete element. I got this information from here: http://cientouno.be/blog/categorie/zend-framework

Thanks a lot to cientouno!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, but, I used the ActionStack for display on every page. And do, I use a form.

```
public function autocompleteAction() {
     $formAutoComplete = new Frontoffice_Form_Autocomplete();
     $this->view->autocompleteElement = $formAutoComplete;
     $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setResponseSegment('autocomplete');
}
```

and, in the layout :

```
<div class="prefix_10 grid_6" id="header_search_engine">
   <?php  echo $this->partial("/common/_search_engine.phtml");
   echo $this->layout()->autocomplete;
   ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the autocompleteElement in the partial view with this code.

```
<div class="prefix_11 grid_5" id="header_search_engine">
        <?php  echo $this->partial("/common/_search_engine.phtml", array('autocompleteElement ' => $this->autocompleteElement);  ?>
</div>
```